# How to pass a variable to the sub make called by foreach function in a Makefile?

Tags: linux, gnu-make, makefile

I want to do sub make in a loop with a variable `KDIR` passed to the Makefile being called in `module/` folder.

```
sub_make=$(MAKE) -C module all KDIR=$(1);

SUB_DIRS= k1 k2 k3 

all:  
    @$(foreach n, $(SUB_DIRS), $(call sub_make, $(n)))
```

The content of Makefile in `module/` folder is very simple as the following:

```
all:
    echo $(KDIR)
```

But I get the following errors:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'k1'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/r/Desktop/work/test/module'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/r/Desktop/work/test/module'
echo 

make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'k2'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/r/Desktop/work/test/module'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/r/Desktop/work/test/module'
echo 

make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'k3'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/r/Desktop/work/test/module'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone solve it ?

Comment: First rule of make debugging: _remove `@` modifiers_ then _look carefully at the command being invoked_.  You should never add `@` until the very last thing after your makefile is completely working.  In fact it's best not to add them at all and use a method such as http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a space. Change

```
@$(foreach n, $(SUB_DIRS), $(call sub_make, $(n)))
```

to:

```
@$(foreach n, $(SUB_DIRS), $(call sub_make,$(n)))
```

With the space,

```
$(MAKE) -C module all KDIR=$(1);
```

will expand to:

```
make -C module all KDIR= k1;
make -C module all KDIR= k2;
make -C module all KDIR= k3;
```

which (hopefully) is obviously wrong.

There are at least two ways to debug your makefile. One is to try `make -n`, which will print out the above. Or you could remove the `@`, which will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

[A final caution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html):

> Be careful when adding whitespace to the arguments to `call`. As with other functions, any whitespace contained in the second and subsequent arguments is kept; this can cause strange effects. It’s generally safest to remove all extraneous whitespace when providing parameters to `call`.